# How to clean the jar jobs on my hadoop client

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

The problem is that the jar files in the /tmp directory (of my client) are not cleaned up after the job is done.
I have the following (simplified) code:

```
public void run() throws IOException {
    PigServer pigServer = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // ... some methods that add to the sb ...

        pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE);
        pigServer.setBatchOn();
        pigServer.registerQuery(sb.toString());                     

        // execute and discard the batch
        pigServer.executeBatch();
        pigServer.discardBatch();
    } finally {
        if (pigServer != null) {
            pigServer.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

To my understanding the pigServer.shutdown() should remove all my temporary files in /tmp. After the job is done, however, my /tmp directory is full of Job9196419177728780689.jar files and an empty pig8776538161976852388tmp subdirectory.

When debugging, I see that a lot of jobs on the (remote) hadoop cluster are being deleted, plus one attempt to delete /tmp/temp2071202241 (local). 
This is not an existing directory on my local system, it seems.

The files do get deleted after I shut down the VM, but this is obviously not what I want to do after every job.
Am I missing something?

Edit: I am not the only one with this problem, the issue is filed under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3338

Edit 2: Possible solution (not by me): http://www.lopakalogic.com/articles/hadoop-articles/pig-keeps-temp-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. Pig creates a temp File by `File.createTempFile` and use `File.deleteOnExit` to remove it when the VM is shuting down. See the code [here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.9.0/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/executionengine/mapReduceLayer/JobControlCompiler.java#407).

How about launching a VM for every Pig script?

Comment: Thank you. Launching a new VM for every script is not something I am looking forward to. At least for now I will continue using my workaround, which is a cron job that will empty the /tmp every once in a while.